# Flash Builder Creative Cloud Error Messages When Testing Simple Program

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, adobe

I am using Flash Builder Creative Cloud (4.7) with Actionscript Project. The project uses AIR SDK 3.4. I am using Starling framework to complete a tutorial for learning. I set up Starling correctly per tutorial. However, when I use this test code from

http://wiki.starling-framework.org/manual/startup_code

I get 53 error messages. The 53 error messages do not appear until I create the Game class. I have changed html file as stated by tutorial to "params.wmode = "direct". I also changed my web browser in the IDE settings to work from Firefox. I do not get any error messages directed from Firefox due to flash errors. So I do not believe it is an issue from not installing the debugger from adobe.

This site (http://wiki.starling-framework.org/manual/startup_code) also states that I should do this:

"If we're talking about an AIR project, you will need to edit the AIR application descriptor, which is probably called “Project-app.xml” or similar, depending on your project name. Find and update the “renderMode” XML tag (which might be commented out) to the value “direct”."

Find this:
</renderMode> -->

Replace with this:
direct

I am also unsure where to find “Project-app.xml” and replace as the above directions state. This is the only other step I have not tried in my troubleshooting.

I am unsure what is causing the 53 error messages when I run the simple test program.

Some of the 53 errors state this:
Access of possibly undefined property backBufferHeight through a reference with static type Context3D.  Painter.as  /Spacer/code/starling/rendering line 126    Flex Problem

Others state this:

Call to a possibly undefined method insertAt through a reference with static type Vector..   DisplayObjectContainer.as   /Spacer/code/starling/display   line 238    Flex Problem

.

Comment: You have set up your project as an AIR project, right ? In this case you should have the application XML in your "src" folder. It is named the same as your project (If your project folder is called "MyApplication" your xml will be called MyApplication-app.xml . This is the file describing various settings for your app including the name the user will see when installed, the icons etc

Comment: The insertAt method has been added pretty recently ...make sure you are using the latest Air SDK.

Comment: I think it was the me not having the latest SDK that was causing the issue. I also did not have my starling framework imported correctly. I found a great tutorial on lynda.com for flash builder 4.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update Air SDK and all your issues will go away.
3.4 is ancient! 
Current stable version of Adobe AIR SDK & Compiler is 21.0.0.198 (you're 18 major versions behind; things have changed, Android, iOS have changed).

Also give [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewforum.php?f=11) a try. Project setup is easy and SDK install is handled by a built in tool. To install the latest SDKs go to Tools -> Install Software wait for them to download and you're good to go.

Comment: I'm going to check out flash develop!